# How to hide the first Y-axis reference line in BEMSimpleLineGraph?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bemsimplelinegraph

The [BEMSimpleLineGraph](https://github.com/Boris-Em/BEMSimpleLineGraph) library is simple and easily customisable.
But there is an extra Y-axis reference line as shown:
How to remove it? Actually there is no need of it.

[image]

Comment: i have download the demo as your given link but demo working perfectly. no extra lines

Comment: The demo is working perfectly. I have used in my project and everything looks fine. but the thing is that there is an extra reference Y axis line as shown in the above image. I couldn't remove it. I tried many ways but failure was the result.